PineScript - "kind of" recursive function smma
I got the following PineScript with a function that I try to wrap my head around but I can't fully understand it:
lengthMA = input(34)

calc_smma(input, len) =>
    smma=na(smma[1]) ? sma(input, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + input) / len
    smma

// ...

hi=calc_smma(high, lengthMA)
lo=calc_smma(low, lengthMA)

The smma is nowhere else defined in the script and I wonder if smma[1] is looking at one earlier position in the timeseries.
Can anyone enlighten me how exactly this function works?
The PineScript documentation about time-series & arrays was not resourceful enough:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/language/time-series/
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/language/arrays/

This could only work in pinescript-v2 or lower.
It is called Self-referenced variable and it is no longer allowed in v3 and higher.
In those versions, you need to declare the variable first and then use the := operator to assign a new value to it.
//@version=5

calc_smma(input, len) =>
    smma = 0.0
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(input, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + input) / len
    smma

And yes. Functions have their own local scope and [1] would return the variable's value on the previous bar if available. Otherwise, it will return na.
